# Access 2010 - query showing running total for multiple records, dropping old record and adding new record on each line

Tags: database, ms-access, sum, cumulative-sum

I have an Access database which is tracking hours used by each employee in each pay period.

I need a query that will allow me to look back in time and see what the total was for **just the last 25 pay periods**, as calculated from **each** of the previous 26 pay periods, **for each employee**.  This a rolling total in which, essentially, records that are 26 pay periods (or more) older must be ignored on a per-line basis.  I have five years' worth of records, and it is unfortunately necessary to retain them all, and it is very important to be able to see what the 26-pay-period running total for each employee was, together with the hours used in a particular pay period.

Basically, we're looking at **51** records total for each employee - the first pay period the query actually *shows*, however, is **26** pay periods ago; it has a running total based on what happened in that pay period plus the previous 25.

**Tables:**
*HoursID*, *EmployeeID*, *PayPeriodID*, *HoursUsed*
*PayPeriodID*, *PayPeriodEndDate*

**Query Results (already working):**
*EmployeeID*, *TotalOfHoursUsedLast26PP* (this query requests a date to count back from)

**Query Results I Need:**
*EmployeeID*, *PayPeriodID*, *HoursUsed*, [*Total Hours Used, Based on the 25 PP immediately previous to this PP*]

I've been messing around with DSum, but I can't figure out how to make it *only* count the last 26 PP, counting the PPs I need, for one employee at a time, for each pay period separately.

To be clear: I need to be able to look back and run this query for 26 pay periods in 2009 or something; in Excel, for one individual employee, we did something that looks like this:

Line32_HoursUsedLast26PP = Line32_HoursUsedThisPP + Line31_HoursUsedLast26PP - Line4_HoursUsedThisPP

The results are something like:

2011-5   -  338.8
2011-6   -  398.5
2011-7   -  428.7
2011-8   -  442.5
2011-9   -  451
2011-10  -  451
2011-11  -  451
2011-12  -  451
2011-13  -  451
2011-14  -  451
2011-15  -  451
2011-16  -  452.4
2011-17  -  453.1
2011-18  -  454.3
2011-19  -  454.3
2011-20  -  455
2011-21  -  456.1
2011-22  -  460.2
2011-23  -  480
2011-24  -  480
2011-25  -  480
2011-26  -  480
2012-01  -  453.2
2012-02  -  381.2
2012-03  -  301.2
2012-04  -  221.2
2012-05  -  141.2
2012-06  -  81.5
2012-07  -  51.3
2012-08  -  37.5
2012-09  -  29
2012-10  -  29
2012-11  -  29
2012-12  -  29
2012-13  -  29
2012-14  -  29
2012-15  -  29
2012-16  -  27.6
2012-17  -  26.9
2012-18  -  25.7
2012-19  -  25.7
2012-20  -  25
2012-21  -  23.9
2012-22  -  19.8
2012-23  -  0

As you can see, the running total goes up *and* down.

This is the actual code I have for the "find total hours in the last 26 pay periods" query; the stuff about certifications, etc., is because in any given pay period, the employees may have hours recorded under multiple certifications.

```
SELECT List_Employees.ID, Sum(Items_Hours_Actually_Taken.HoursActual) AS SumOfHoursActual
FROM (List_Pay_Periods INNER JOIN (List_Employees INNER JOIN (Items_Certifications INNER JOIN Items_Hours_Actually_Taken ON Items_Certifications.[CertificationID] = Items_Hours_Actually_Taken.[HoursActualCertificationID]) ON List_Employees.ID = Items_Certifications.[CertificationEmployeeID]) ON List_Pay_Periods.[PayPeriodID] = Items_Hours_Actually_Taken.[HoursActualPayPeriod]) INNER JOIN Last_26_PP_From_Today ON List_Pay_Periods.PayPeriodID = Last_26_PP_From_Today.PayPeriodID
GROUP BY List_Employees.ID;
```

In case it's not clear, this query depends on a separate query, called Last_26_PP_From_Today:

```
SELECT List_Pay_Periods.PayPeriodID, List_Pay_Periods.PPEnd
FROM List_Pay_Periods
WHERE (((List_Pay_Periods.PPEnd)<Date() And (List_Pay_Periods.PPEnd)>(Date()-14)));
```

I also have a query that switches to find the last 26 pay periods from any particular date:

```
PARAMETERS [Date] DateTime;
SELECT List_Pay_Periods.PayPeriodID, List_Pay_Periods.PPEnd
FROM List_Pay_Periods
WHERE (((List_Pay_Periods.PPEnd)<[Date] And (List_Pay_Periods.PPEnd)>([Date]-14)));
```

The brute-force method I thought of in desperation involved a cascading series of Make Table queries, which was when I decided perhaps someone here could offer something cleaner.

**Update**

Thanks to Gord, I now have everything working except that I don't see the Pay Period numbers:

```
SELECT hbep1.Employee, hbep1.PP

(

SELECT Sum(hbep2.Hours) 
        FROM Hours_By_Employee_Per_PP AS hbep2
        WHERE hbep2.Employee=hbep1.Employee 
            AND (hbep2.PP Between hbep1.[PP]-25 And hbep1.[PP])

    ) AS SumLast26

FROM Hours_By_Employee_Per_PP AS hbep1;
```

That gets me:

```
Employee    SumLast26
2           12
2           12
2           12
2           18
2           91
3           4
3           8
3           88
3           168
3           180
5           15
5           15
5           15
7           43
7           61
7           75
7           97
7           106
7           121
9           19
9           0
```

Comment: re: Pay Period numbers not showing - You seem to be missing the comma after `hbep1.PP` on the first line.

Comment: You are pretty much a god among men, just so you know.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I would have settled for "Prince", but thanks all the same. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this points you in the right direction:

I started with a table I called [Hours_by_Empl_PP] which has the total hours for each Employee in each individual Pay_Period.

```
EmployeeID  PayPeriodID HoursUsed
1           1           3
1           2           7
1           3           4
1           4           4
1           5           5
1           6           8
1           7           5
2           1           1
2           2           2
2           3           1
2           4           0
2           5           0
2           6           1
2           7           2
```

If your table data has multiple records for a given (Employee + Pay_Period) you can create a simple aggregation query to total up the values...

```
SELECT EmployeeID, PayPeriodID, SUM(HoursUsedToday) AS HoursUsed
FROM YourRawData
GROUP BY EmployeeID, PayPeriodID
```

...save *that* as [Hours_by_Empl_PP], and use that instead of a table.

The next step was to create a query to sum up the number of hours over a 4-period window. (I chose 4 instead of 26 just to make it easier to check my work.) This window includes the current Pay_Period and the previous three.

```
SELECT hbep1.EmployeeID, hbep1.PayPeriodID, 
    (
        SELECT Sum(hbep2.HoursUsed) 
        FROM Hours_by_Empl_PP hbep2
        WHERE hbep2.EmployeeID=hbep1.EmployeeID 
            AND (hbep2.PayPeriodID Between hbep1.[PayPeriodID]-3 And hbep1.[PayPeriodID])
    ) AS Sum_of_Hours_last_4_PPs
FROM Hours_by_Empl_PP hbep1;
```

This query gives me

```
EmployeeID  PayPeriodID Sum_of_Hours_last_4_PPs
1           1           3
1           2           10
1           3           14
1           4           18
1           5           20
1           6           21
1           7           22
2           1           1
2           2           3
2           3           4
2           4           4
2           5           3
2           6           2
2           7           3
```

Note that the query assumes that PayPeriodID values are sequential and in chronological order. You could achieve the same result using [PayPeriodEndDate] values, but that would mean another JOIN and I wanted to keep the example as clear as possible.

That's it, really. You can just save that query with a name like [Hours_by_Empl_4PP_window] and use it in your queries to JOIN on other tables (for Employee name, etc.) and take it from there.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't try it till I get back to work; I'll let you know on Monday if it worked.

Comment: Thank you!  I just updated the post to show my results - everything worked great, except for some reason it's not showing me the pay period ID numbers.