# SQL Code for Running Total does not recognise table name

Tags: ms-access-2010, cumulative-sum

I have a question on creating running totals in MS Access 2010 similar to the one here:

[Access 2010 - query showing running total for multiple records, dropping old record and adding new record on each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553928/access-2010-query-showing-running-total-for-multiple-records-dropping-old-rec)

However when I input the equivalent code from that thread I get an error saying that the database cannot be found (Access seems to think the table I have specified is the database name)

Here is the code from the original thread:-

```
SELECT hbep1.EmployeeID, hbep1.PayPeriodID, 
    (
    SELECT Sum(hbep2.HoursUsed) 
    FROM Hours_by_Empl_PP hbep2
    WHERE hbep2.EmployeeID=hbep1.EmployeeID 
        AND (hbep2.PayPeriodID Between hbep1.[PayPeriodID]-3 
        And hbep1.[PayPeriodID])
    ) AS Sum_of_Hours_last_4_PPs
FROM Hours_by_Empl_PP hbep1;
```

Here is the code I inputted into my query:-

```
SELECT 
    V4_Try.ID_NIS_INV_HDR,
    V4_Try.ID_ITM, 
    V4_Try.RunTot3, 
    V4_Try.BomVsActQty,
    DMin("RunTot3","V4_Try","[ID_Itm]=" & [ID_ITM]) AS IDItmMin,  
    DMax("RunTot3","V4_Try","[ID_Itm]=" & [ID_ITM]) AS IDItmMax, 
    (
       SELECT Sum([V4_Try].[BomVsActQty])
       FROM [V4_Try].[BomVsActQty]
       WHERE [V4_Try].[ID_ITM]=[V4_Try].[ID_ITM]
           AND (IDItmMax < IDItmMin) 
    ) AS RunTot6
FROM V4_Try
ORDER BY V4_Try.ID_ITM, V4_Try.RunTot3;
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice is that the main query uses `DMax()` and `DMin()` to create some aliased columns

```
...
DMin("RunTot3","V4_Try","[ID_Itm]=" & [ID_ITM]) AS IDItmMin,  
DMax("RunTot3","V4_Try","[ID_Itm]=" & [ID_ITM]) AS IDItmMax,
...
```

and then the subquery tries to use those aliases in its WHERE clause

```
(
   SELECT ...
   WHERE...
       AND (IDItmMax < IDItmMin) 
) AS RunTot6
```

I'm pretty sure that the subquery will have no knowledge of the column aliases in the "parent" query, so they may be the items that are unrecognized.

Comment: +1 -- Right on.  I couldn't put my finger on that, but I'm sure it was bothering me.

Answer (score 0):

Start by running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM V4_Try;
```

Then develop for complexity.  Build the nested query before anything else.  When you know that runs, try adding your aliases, then the `DMax()` function, and so on.  Isolate the point at which you have an error popping up.

This is the process to fix a query.

Oh, and please specify the precise error that is raised by Access.  Also, if this is being run from VBA, please let us know because that affects your trouble-shooting.